# How to continue a CAKeyframeAnimation when UIViewController is not displayed anymore?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, core-animation

I'm starting a basic animation (UIImageView that follows a path) with this code:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *bounceAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
bounceAnimation.path = cgpath;
bounceAnimation.duration = 40.0;
bounceAnimation.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAuto;
[img.layer addAnimation:bounceAnimation forKey:@"animateLayer"];
```

The animation works fine.

But when I go to another UIViewController and then come back to this UIViewController,
my UIImageView is not visible anymore, and the animation doesn't run anymore too.

It looks like as soon as I leave the current UIViewController, the animation stops.

Is there a way to avoid this behavior?

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Alex

More details:

I added a Timer that draws something under the animated UIImageView.
Here is the code called by this timer :

```
CALayer* _l=_v.layer.presentationLayer; // _v is my animated UIImageView
CGRect r=_l.frame;
img.center=CGPointMake(r.origin.x+r.size.width/2.0, r.origin.y+r.size.height/2.0);
```

As soon as I change the current UIViewController, the img.center is located under the initial position of my UIImageView => the UIIMageView is not moving anymore :(

Comment: I think the animation didn't stop.The question is why the UIImageView invisible.Do you set the UIImageView hidden or some other property?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. It still doesn't work.
I added some details on my first post.

Answer (score 1):

make sure that when you leave your view controller it does not get deallocated

add in the viewController where the animation is:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"did get deallocated");
}
```

then in your animation check the fillMode property `kCAFillModeBoth` or `kCAFillModeForward`:

```
bounceAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
```

Exemple

```
CALayer * layer       = [CALayer layer];
layer.anchorPoint     = CGPointZero;
layer.frame           = self.creator.animationLayer.bounds;
layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
layer.opacity         = 0.f;
layer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspectFill;
layer.contents        = (__bridge id)image;
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. It still doesn't work.
I added some details on my first post.

Comment: also you should use keyframe animation on CALayer not UIImageView.

Comment: That's done here : [img.layer addAnimation:bounceAnimation forKey:@"animateLayer"]; isn't it?

Comment: yes, this CALayer backs a UIView. CALayer backing UIView are modified CALayer and behave differently in certain circumstances than direct CALayer.

Comment: thanks for this tip, but unfortunately it doesn't work better :(

Comment: well, the problem must be most likely somewhere else then... sry